# How to get return value from function thread using future and promise in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, promise, future

I have a below code where I am using `future` and `promise` to get return value from a function. Below is the code:

```
void myfunction2(string msg, std::promise<std::string> && prms)
{
    prms.set_value(msg);
}

int main()
{
    std::promise<std::string> prms;
    std::future<std::string> ftr = prms.get_future();
    while (1)
    {
        thread t1(myfunction2, "Hello thread", std::move(prms));

        cout << "Main loop" << endl;

        std::string str = ftr.get();
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
        t1.join();
        Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

It outputs below:

```
Main loop
Hello thread
Main loop
```

As it is inside the while(1) so when the controls comes back to `std::string str = ftr.get();` it throws some exception

`Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFDD0F1A388 in Testcode.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::future_error at memory location 0x00000003FDCFF740.`

If I run it without while(1) this will work but I actually need to run it inside the `while(1) loop. How can I resolve this issue.

Comment: The second iteration of the loop will use moved-from `prms`, that's not good thing to do. What is the purpose of this loop? Are you sure you want to create another on each iteration and just wait for it?

Comment: You can set promise only once. Remove the loop or bring the promise within scope of  loop.

Comment: The first time through the loop a thread is created with an argument that's moved from `prms`. The second time through the loop the same thing is done again, but `prms` has already been moved from, so it is no longer useful. Don't reuse a `promise` or a `future`. Create one each time you need it, in this case, inside the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only set the value of a promise once. To use loop in your program, relegate the promise and future variables within the scope of the loop,  like so:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        std::promise<std::string> prms;
        std::future<std::string> ftr = prms.get_future();

        thread t1(myfunction2, "Hello thread", std::move(prms));

        cout << "Main loop" << endl;

        std::string str = ftr.get();
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
        t1.join();
        Sleep(2000);

        if (++i > 3) break; // no infinite loop
    }
}
```

**Edited:** In your code, other threads will not spawn till the first one joins and so on. Code snippet edited to allow concurrent execution. Here all the threads are spawn to allow parallel execution and later joined collectively at the end.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::thread, std::future<std::string>>> threads;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::promise<std::string> prms;
        std::future<std::string> fut = prms.get_future();

        thread th(myfunction2, "Hello thread", std::move(prms));
        threads.push_back(make_pair(move(th), move(fut)));
    }

    for (auto& e : threads)
    {
        auto th = move(e.first);
        auto fut = move(e.second);
        std::string str = fut.get();
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
        th.join();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks but what is the purpose of i here.?

Comment: @SAndrew: Your loop is infinite one.

Comment: @SAndrew: Warning: your threads are not executing concurrently.

Comment: How can I run them concurrently.?

Answer (score 3):

As per: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/set_value

> An exception is thrown if there is **no shared state** or the shared state
>   **already stores** a value or exception.

With your code it seems like you are trying to store more than once a value inside a promise.
Secondly, as noted by Quimby, in the second iteration, the passed promise has been already moved from, so there is no shared state (see the docs about move ctor for `std::promise` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/promise). To me it is unclear what you are trying to achieve. Regardless, remember that `std::promise` and `std::future` are basically a one-shot communication channel and the shared state can be set only once.

I rewrote your code to allow it to run, creating a new `promise/future` pair for each iteration.

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>



void myfunction2(std::string msg, std::promise<std::string> && prms)
{
    prms.set_value(msg);
}

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        std::promise<std::string> prms;
        std::future<std::string> ftr = prms.get_future();

        thread t1(myfunction2, "Hello thread", std::move(prms));

        cout << "Main loop" << endl;

        std::string str = ftr.get();
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
        t1.join();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: @L.F. thanks for pointing out the issue. I corrected the code